# JavaConfig & web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Как в Spring проекте сделать конфигурацию через WebMvcConfigurerAdapter и web.xml одновременно ? У меня проблема с кодировкой jsp страниц, которые отображают иероглифы. Нашел на форуме решение, в котором указано, что нужно добавить web.xml и сделать в нем конфигурацию jsp.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>





" media="all" />

">

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>
                <spring:message code="label.user.registration.page.title" />
            </h1>
        </header>
        <div class="form">
            <!--
                Ensure that when the form is submitted, a POST request is send to url
                '/user/register'.
            -->
            <form:form action="/Dronesfree/user/register" commandName="user"
                method="POST" role="form">
                <!-- Add CSRF token to the request. -->
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <!--
                    If the user is using social sign in, add the signInProvider
                    as a hidden field.
                -->
                <c:if test="${user.signInProvider != null}">
                    <form:hidden path="signInProvider" />
                </c:if>
                <p class="contact">
                    <label class="control-label" for="user-firstName"><spring:message
                            code="label.user.firstName" />:</label>
                    <form:errors id="error-firstName" path="firstName"
                        cssClass="help-block" />
                </p>
                <form:input id="firstName" path="firstName" cssClass="form-control" />

                <p class="contact">
                    <label class="control-label" for="user-lastName"><spring:message
                            code="label.user.lastName" />:</label>
                    <form:errors id="error-lastName" path="lastName"
                        cssClass="help-block" />
                </p>

                <form:input id="user-lastName" path="lastName"
                    cssClass="form-control" />


                <p class="contact">
                    <label class="control-label" for="user-email"><spring:message
                            code="label.user.email" />:</label>
                    <form:errors id="error-email" path="email" cssClass="help-block" />
                </p>
                <!--
                            Add the email field to the form and ensure
                            that validation errors are shown.
                        -->
                <form:input id="user-email" path="email" cssClass="form-control" />



                <p class="contact">
                    <label class="control-label" for="user-username"><spring:message
                            code="label.user.username" />:</label>
                    <form:errors id="error-username" path="username"
                        cssClass="help-block" />
                </p>
                <!--
                            Add the email field to the form and ensure
                            that validation errors are shown.
                        -->
                <form:input id="user-username" path="username"
                    cssClass="form-control" />


                <!--
                    If the user is creating a normal user account, add password fields
                    to the form.
                -->
                <c:if test="${user.signInProvider == null}">

                    <p class="contact">
                        <label class="control-label" for="user-password"><spring:message
                                code="label.user.password" />:</label>
                        <form:errors id="error-password" path="password"
                            cssClass="help-block" />
                    </p>
                    <!--
                                Add the password field to the form and ensure
                                that validation errors are shown.
                            -->
                    <form:password id="user-password" path="password"
                        cssClass="form-control" />

                    <p class="contact">
                        <label class="control-label" for="user-passwordVerification"><spring:message
                                code="label.user.passwordVerification" />:</label>
                        <form:errors id="error-passwordVerification"
                            path="passwordVerification" cssClass="help-block" />
                    </p>
                    <!--
                                Add the passwordVerification field to the form and ensure
                                that validation errors are shown.
                            -->
                    <form:password id="user-passwordVerification"
                        path="passwordVerification" cssClass="form-control" />


                </c:if>
                <!-- Add the submit button to the form. -->

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    <spring:message code="label.user.registration.submit.button" />
                </button>
            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</sec:authorize>
<!--
    If the user is authenticated, show a help message instead
    of registration form.
-->
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <p>
        <spring:message code="text.registration.page.authenticated.user.help" />
    </p>
</sec:authorize>
```

Comment: Если что-то можно сконфигурировать в `web.xml`, то это же можно сделать и программно.

Comment: Можно увидеть jsp страницу, которая проблемная? Все что делается в xml все можно устроить и в Java-config, хотя это спор еще тот, что в этом случае лучше.

Comment: @flybox опубликовал страницу jsp

Answer (score 1):

Самое очевидное, что может быть, это кодировка Java-файлов не совпадает с UTF-8. И в этом случае будут отображаться иероглифы в JSP. Сейчас протестировал на своем маленьком, когда-то собранном проекте, там все отобразилось корректно. Посмотрите файлы кодировок, которые содержит проект. Если используете Idea то внизу справа. Так же попробуйте задать в настройках кодировку всего проекта.